# how to use loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

```
<div class="elem">
    <div data="1">
    <div data="11">test1</div>
        <div data="12">test2</div>
    </div>
    <div data="2">
        <div data="21">test3</div>
        <div data="22">test4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in above example I would like to print data value of each element , so please help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You can find all `div`s inside div with `class="elem"`, then iterate all divs to read data attribute using `.each()`

```js
$(function(){
   $('div.elem div').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('data'));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem">
    <div data="1">
    <div data="11">test1</div>
        <div data="12">test2</div>
    </div>
    <div data="2">
        <div data="21">test3</div>
        <div data="22">test4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @support If answer help you then please mark and up vote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is used as a suffix for setting data property to element. You should use it as `data-propname`

and then use `.data()` to get them:

```
$('.elem div').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('propname'))
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.data('propname')`?

Comment: @Barmar: indeed yes.. :)

Comment: its not exact the code that will run but it helped me to understand